# Помогите со слайдером

Tags: jquery

Ребят, есть такой [слайдер](http://www.ajaxblender.com/script-sources/bgstretcher/demo/index.html).

Можно ли реализовать так, чтобы блок с контентом менялся при смене слайда? Или, может, кто подскажет такой плагин?)

Answer (score 1):

Найдите в плагине event где меняется картинка и после ее смены, или перед ней, отправляйте аякс запрос и потом вставляйте полученный результат в блок контента.